# Getting select rows from ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

How do I create (or access) an array of selected rows in my [ng-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid)?

---

#### [Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#api) (scroll to "Grid options")

```
id                 | default value | definition
-----------------------------------------------
selectedItems      |       []      | all of the items selected in the grid.
                                     In single select mode there will only
                                     be one item in the array.
```

#### index.html

```html
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

    <h3>Rows selected</h3>
    <pre>{{selectedItems}}</pre>
</body>
```

#### main.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

[Plnkr for the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/loRe5d?p=preview) (and to run it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on the doc, `selectedItems` should be a property of `$scope.gridOptions`, so try this:

Controller

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', selectedItems: [] };
```

HTML

```
<pre>{{gridOptions.selectedItems}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, had thought it was a default option; due to it having a default value; guess I won't expect that again. It's working :)

Answer (score 7):

You can get selected items of ng-grid 2.x from:

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.selectedItems
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 3 you can do:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){

  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.mySelectedRows=$scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
}
```

Refer to http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi for more info.

Comment: I had multiple grids on my page and it seemed to cause problems with setting the `$scope.mySelectedRows`, even with unique values, I am not sure why as it should work fine.  I was however still able to get to each grid using `$scope.uniqueGridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()`.

Answer (score 3):

For 3.0, you can capture rows as they're selected like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
    $log.log(msg);
  });
};
```

More info here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

Comment: Although this is an acceptable solution, I prefer the answer from `Ewald Stieger` because it has less code to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to read a list of selected rows at the moment.  The option appears to have moved, I can now find this in:

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.config.selectedItems
```

It appears to be read-only

Comment: This was a life saver for me. The selectedItems property I tried to set this to was not working -- this does!