# Pre-Select rows on load with angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to select certain rows on page load(working days)

[image]

This is the plunker
 `plnkr.co/edit/48NyxngWNGIlOps1Arew?p=preview`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following property to your `$scope.gridOptions` object :

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
}
```

This sets a `$scope.gridApi` so you can access it if you need it outside of this function.

You need to call the `modifyRows` method in order to be able to make changes to your rows.

Then the first row is selected (just as an example).

http://plnkr.co/edit/mvwlfaJiPDysbn2IrNpv?p=preview

To select the working days, maybe you can try replacing the last line by something like this :

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (row.isWorkingDay()) {
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[index]);
    }
});
```

`row.isWorkingDay` can simply check if the day is among a list of given days.

If your data is loaded by an async call you can simply select the rows in the callback :

```
asyncCall.then(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
});
```

Comment: `onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
}`
This not work for me, the first row is not selected

Comment: maybe is because i set the data after an async call?

Comment: Yes, that may be the case. You can simply move the code that modifies and select rows in your async call callback and use `$scope.gridApi`there since you saved it in the `onRegisterApi` function. check my edit

Comment: Works nicely. If data comes in async then placing the ui-grid inside a directive on which you declare ng-if="data" may help.

Comment: @Komo would you have a look to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201642/angular-ui-grid-line-selection-is-not-working)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer did not work reliably. Using the ui-grid inside a component, and setting `gridOptions.data` to a property bound to the component, `api.grid.modifyRows()` threw an exception because the columns had not been created which is done in the ui-grid `dataWatchFunction`.

Here is what worked for me. Maybe it can help someone else.

```
gridOptions =
  {
  /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* `data` Property - Sets/Returns `rawData`. Setter calls */
  /* `selectRows()` to select rows from the loaded items.   */
  /*                                                        */
  /* If `onRegisterApi()` has not been executed, the API is */
  /* not available and the grid has not been configured.    */
  /* `selectRows()` is called in `onRegisterAPI()`.         */
  /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
  get data()     { return (this.rawData || (this.rawData = [])); },
  set data(data) 
    { 
    this.rawData = data;
    if (this.api)
      this.selectRows(this);
    },

  /*------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Select rows for the initial setting of `data`. */
  /*------------------------------------------------*/
  onRegisterApi: function(api) 
    {
    this.selectRows(this);
    },

  /*------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* `selectRows` is called after the `data` property has */
  /* been updated and waits for a ROW data change event.  */
  /*------------------------------------------------------*/
  selectRows: function(self)
    {
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Register handler to select rows on next ROW event that have */
    /* `IWantSelected` set `true`. Deregister after execution.     */
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
    var deregister = self.api.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function(grid) 
      {
      self.data.filter(function(item) { return item.IWantSelected; }).some(function(item)
        {
        self.api.selection.selectRow(item);
        });
      deregister();
      }, [uiGridConstants.dataChange.ROW]);
    }
  };
```