# How to select the first row by default in UI-grid in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How select the first Row default in UI-Grid in Angular JS:

I tried below code, but it is not working:

```
 $scope.gridOptions.data =  someData;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
    },
    100)
```

and Tried even below solution also but this is also not working :

```
 $scope.gridOptions.data =  someData;
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
```

Could any one please suggest how to get it. Thanks in advance

Comment: which version is your ui-grid?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ycF3r1zu44hFTyn7rmG6?p=preview

Comment: Hi @VinoDang, I am using 3.1.0 UI-Grid and angular js version is 1.5.0-rc.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code requires ui-grid v3.0.0-rc.22, you can call modifyRows as follows:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data =  someData;
$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
```

No `$timeout` needed.

you can visit this page:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2267
or [Angular ngGrid select row on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504761/angular-nggrid-select-row-on-page-load)

if the above code doesn't work, you can try the following code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    ... 
    onRegisterApi : function (gridApi) { 
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;   
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data); 
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
     }
};
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it is not working, could you suggest any other solution, Thanks for advance !

Comment: could u have a plunker? if you have one, it would be helpful to resolve it!

Comment: try it like this:
$scope.gridOptions = {
...
                onRegisterApi : function (gridApi) {
                    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
                    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
                }
            };