# Updating elements in selectedItems array in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-grid

I am getting the selected rows of my ng-grid and showing certain values in a separated array.
My problem is that when I change some values in the selected row, I need to update the element rather than pushing a new pair of values.

```
$scope.$watch('mySelectedItems', function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.selectedItems.forEach(function(entry) {
        var myEntry = {unit: entry.myUnit, quantity: entry.qty, sku: entry.sku};
        $scope.result1.push(myEntry);
    });
}, true);
```

Note: The `mySelectedItems` is just a new array containing the same data in `selectedItems[]` (ng-grid's default array)

I know it has to do with the `push()` function, but I can't find a way to update the existing pair of values.
Has anyone did something similar in the past?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  Why is the code you provided not accomplishing what you want it to?

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle and show the problem?

Comment: The actual code is pasting each new pair of values every time I update the row values (for example, a new numbre in quantity or a new unit).

So Im getting
    [{"unit":"Ton","quantity":"1","sku":"106029072"},    {"unit":"Ton","quantity":"2","sku":"106029072"}]

As you can see the SKU (ID) is the same so it should be only one set of values for that product.

Comment: I am creating a plunker in the next mins

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create a plunker due to certain config in the server.
Basically I am trying to update an element in the array with specific values rather than pushing a new pair of values with new values.

Comment: I was able to build it :)
http://plnkr.co/QTdoggyKhubbB3F3VeO1

Answer (score 0):

Check if this work

Controller

$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', selectedItems: [] };
HTML

```
{{gridOptions.selectedItems}}
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875283/getting-select-rows-from-ng-grid).

Comment: This doesn't help... I am already getting the selectedItems. I have other problem as stated in the question.

Comment: got it, waiting for the plunker to fully understand it

Comment: I still did not understood what you are trying for, if you want to change an element in an array I did some thing like this before. http://plnkr.co/edit/PUTBwgkznW6OjXHxK5UJ?p=preview

Comment: do you want only specific objects copied to other array?

Comment: Madhured, I already fix this :) check my answer above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by modifying the watch function with a new array and adding a second array outside of it. You can check the function in lines 28 to 36 in the js. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the position of the item you want to update, then replace it using the indexer.

```
$scope.$watch('mySelectedItems', function() {
   $scope.gridOptions.selectedItems.forEach(function(entry) {
      var myEntry = {unit: entry.myUnit, quantity: entry.qty, sku: entry.sku};
      var position = $scope.result1.map(function(item) { return item.sku; }).indexOf(myEntry.sku);
      if(position != -1) $scope.result1[position] = myEntry;
  });
}, true);
```