# Where can I get Angular ui-grid selected items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Testing out Angular ui-grid (ng-grid v.3.0). Can not for the life of me find the selected row. I just want to grab the rows or even row ID of row when a user clicks it. Found the top comment here but I think this is outdated:  [Getting select rows from ng-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875283/getting-select-rows-from-ng-grid?answertab=active#tab-top)

Does anyone know where the `gridOptions.selectedItems` is being stored in 3.0?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for ? 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

1. Activate grid selection capabilities with the ui-grid-selection tag (and ui.grid.selection module registration in your app
2. register gridApi and use gridApi.selection to access getSelectedRows()

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the steps above https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188783/2658127, you might have to invoke it through a ng-click event to get the actual value/object. At least that's how I had it working.

```
Eg:
$scope.selectRow = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
};
```

And call selectRow() from the template.

This is for anybody who have been confused like I did, considering the fact that ui-grid does not have the best documentation (specially for this select portion).

Comment: Thanks Rajush, I appreciate the extra info!

Answer (score 16):

The easiest approach is:

1. Register the gridApi by adding this your controller:

   `$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
      $scope.myGridApi = gridApi;
      };`
2. Access the array of selected items:

   `$scope.myGridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();`

Answer (score 0):

With grid ui you have to use the `selection.on.rowSelectionChanged` to update a scope variable that store the selectedItem.
In this way you can use the value in a binding expression.

```
var SelectController = function($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.selectedItem = null;

    $scope.gridOptions = {
            data : 'articles',
            enableRowSelection : true,
            multiSelect : false,
            enableRowHeaderSelection : false,
            ...
        };

        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
            // set gridApi on scope
            this.$scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }.bind(this);
        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
            // set gridApi on scope
            this.$scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            this.$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,
                    function(row) {
                        this.$scope.selectedItem = row.entity;
                    }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this);
```

Use a an array instead of a plain object if you need multiple selection.