# Binding ui-grid from property of selected row in another ui-grid (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to have two ui-grid's. One ui-grid is databound to data (this works fine). When I select a row, I want a second ui-grid to databind to a property of the selected row in the first ui-grid. I come from a "WPF World" where this is straightforward and literally would take one or two lines of code. I think the main issue I'm having is exposing the selectedRow's data object... I've found some similar examples online but they all add listeners, get the index of the row, etc. It seems like this should be simpler than this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but I figured it out - the documentation appeared to be lacking. I used this to get me closer: [Where can I get Angular ui-grid selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188565/where-can-i-get-angular-ui-grid-selected-items)

I wanted the object to bind too though and eventually figured out that the selected object is **row.entity**! Hope this helps someone!