# Get Selected value from ui-grid using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In My project,we used data grid using AngularJS  Implementation  as follows.

```
<div  id="entityGrid" ui-grid="selectedOptions" ui-grid-selection data-ng-model="selectedOptions"></div>
```

i can get selected item in grid as below using angular.js .

```
"entity" :  $scope.createString($scope.selectedOptions.data)
```

but i also want to get selected item in grid using jquery/javascript due to some requirement..
i tried to get value using jquery as below. but it didn't work.

```
var entity = $('#entityGrid option:selected');
```

please help here.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear. I wonder if you could provide a plunker of your codes.

Here is one: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/3KXrUuCsSACuhefmyzxN?p=preview

When you click "Copy" button, the following function is invoked:

```
$scope.copySelection = function (){
    $scope.retainSelection = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();    
};
```

What you get in `$scope.retainSelection` is an object of key:value pairs. You can access which ever key of it.

Here is another question talking about this:

[Where can I get Angular ui-grid selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188565/where-can-i-get-angular-ui-grid-selected-items)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't provide plunker of my code due to  policies.   regarding another question link

Comment: ,I can't provide plunker of my code due to  policies.  regarding another question link, I am able to  get selectedRows in angular js function. but function in that controller scope of angular js.   but  i want create  function to be called  from another js file outside scope controller. so one way to do it create javascript/jquery function which is called from anywhere in my project.  so i tried to get selected rows using jquery as mention in my question . but it didn't work. do you any other soln to get selected rows using jqery/js.