# Angular ui-grid 3.0 get selected rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27166654/379105) states that this code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.mySelectedRows=$scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
}
```

Should work in order to get the selected rows, but to me it returns always [], to get track of selected rows I have to call `gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()` each time a selection event is triggered, is this correct ?

What I want to achieve is to do my own footer that tracks the number of selected rows of the grid, is this the correct way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already an example of showing the number of selected elements in the footer.

This plnkr shows the selected items footer. http://plnkr.co/edit/jc1YPCXBmfOKWyu8sLkx?p=preview

If you want to do further analysis on the selected row you can register a listener for the row selection and act on that.

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
      //set gridApi on scope
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
        $log.log(msg);
      });

      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope,function(rows){
        var msg = 'rows changed ' + rows.length;
        $log.log(msg);
      });
    };
```

Comment: that's indeed the way I did it finally, registering the rowSelectionChangedEvent and tracking the number of selected items

Answer (score 6):

I have it working w/o having to use the event trigger.  I added a function, tied it to a button and can retrieve selected items only when I need them.

```js
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'data',
  enableRowSelection: true,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) { //register grid data first within the gridOptions
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
//this is the on click function
$scope.getCurrentSelection = function() {
  var currentSelection = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
  console.log(currentSelection);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is work for me when selectAll function activated  i have get the all selected rows.

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope,function(rows){
                    console.log(row);
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'data',
  enableRowSelection: true,
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) { //register grid data first within the gridOptions
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
```

After you have access to the variable {{vm.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length}} in template html directily.